# Save only end line

Tags: c#

I have problem with reading a file.

I must write program which take numbers from polish lottery(saved in .txt) and add this to list and answer to questions.

Anyway.. My algorithm save only end line.. I should save all lines in List.. :)

```
        string line;
        List<Losuj> losowanko = new List<Losuj>();

        Losuj pomocnik = new Losuj();


        StreamReader file =
               new StreamReader(@"D:\bawmy się\2# apka\Lotto\Lotto\plik.txt");
           while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
           {
            // Console.WriteLine(line);
            string[] podzialka = line.Split(new string[] { ".", " ", "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);



            pomocnik.NumerLosowania = Int32.Parse(podzialka[0]);
            pomocnik.JakiDzien = Int32.Parse(podzialka[2]);
            pomocnik.JakiMiesiac =Int32.Parse(podzialka[3]);
            pomocnik.JakiRok=Int32.Parse(podzialka[4]);
              for (int i = 5, lo=0; i < 11; i++,lo++)
            {
                pomocnik.Los[lo] =Int32.Parse(podzialka[i]);
            }
            losowanko.Add(pomocnik);

        }


        file.Close();
```

Answer (score 6):

move Losuj object create line to inside the while loop, otherwise you are changing and adding same object again and again

```
    using(StreamReader file =
           new StreamReader(@"D:\bawmy się\2# apka\Lotto\Lotto\plik.txt"))
    {
       while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
        Losuj pomocnik = new Losuj();
        // Console.WriteLine(line);
        string[] podzialka = line.Split(new string[] { ".", " ", "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        pomocnik.NumerLosowania = Int32.Parse(podzialka[0]);
        pomocnik.JakiDzien = Int32.Parse(podzialka[2]);
        pomocnik.JakiMiesiac =Int32.Parse(podzialka[3]);
        pomocnik.JakiRok=Int32.Parse(podzialka[4]);
          for (int i = 5, lo=0; i < 11; i++,lo++)
        {
            pomocnik.Los[lo] =Int32.Parse(podzialka[i]);
        }
        losowanko.Add(pomocnik);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid such errors (wrong list items creation) I suggest *generating* `losowanko` via *Linq*. You should

- read the file by lines
- split each line
- create `Losuj` instance
- materialize the `IEnumerable<Losuj>` into `List<Losuj>`

Implementation:

```
   List<Losuj> losowanko = File
     .ReadLines(@"D:\bawmy się\2# apka\Lotto\Lotto\plik.txt")
     .Select(line => line.Split(new string[] { ".", " ", "," }, StringSplitOptions.None))
     .Select(items => { 
        Losuj item = new Losuj() {
          NumerLosowania = Int32.Parse(items[0]),
          JakiDzien      = Int32.Parse(items[2]), 
          JakiMiesiac    = Int32.Parse(items[3]),
          JakiRok        = Int32.Parse(items[4])}; 

        for (int i = 5, lo = 0; i < 11; i++, lo++)
          item[lo] = Int32.Parse(items[i]); 

        return item;})
     .ToList();
```